# How to access a variable defined by for loop, inside a nested block, when included in a horizontally reusable template called by the use method

Tags: symfony, twig

***NOTE:** This is pretty complex. But if you wade through it, you will be rewarded to learn useful information about the [horizontal reuse of templates in Twig, with the `use` method](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/use.html)!*

I am using the `use` method in Twig 1.16 in order to include a reusable template in a way that lets me extend the blocks (something you can't do if you `include` the template).

I have a template called `Cms/ListBase.html.twig` that uses the `use` statement to include a reusable template `Cms/includes/ListBase-Include.html.twig`. And then I have a template called `Cms/ContentList.html.twig` that extends `Cms/ListBase.html.twig`. When I do this, I can easily overwrite blocks in the `Cms/includes/ListBase-Include.html.twig` and when I do, the values in a block within a `for` loop, are accessible.

However, if I try to overwrite the blocks, directly in the same file that uses the `use` statement, it lets me overwrite them, but when I call the variable within the block which is inside the `for`, the variables aren't accessible.

**Cms/includes/ListBase-Include.html.twig**

*The layout that gets reused.*

```
{% block listBlock %}
    {% block listData %}
            <div id="listContainer" class="table-responsive">
                <table class="list table table-striped table-hover table-condensed">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                        {% block listHead %}
                            <th class="type"> Name </th>
                            <th class="title"> Title </th>
                            <th class="status"> Status </th>
                            <th class="action">Action</th>
                        {% endblock listHead %}
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    {#
                    NOTE: Normally, any template that extends the listRow, has access to 
                    the 'entity' variable that is within the 'for loop' scope. However, if 
                    this include is accessed with the 'use' and then tried to extend in the
                    same file, it doesn't have access to `entity`.
                    #}


                    {% for entity in view.data.list %}
                        {% block listRow %}
                            <tr>
                                <td class="type"> [Insert Data] </td>
                                <td class="title"> [Insert Data] </td>
                                <td class="status"> [Insert Data] </td>
                                <td class="action"> [Insert Actions] </td>
                            </tr>
                        {% endblock listRow %}
                    {% endfor %}

                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
    {% endblock listData %}

{% endblock listBlock %}
```

**Cms/ListBase.html.twig**

*The layout that uses the include.*

```
# Include the reusable listBlock #}
{% use 'GutensiteCmsBundle:Cms:includes/ListBase-Include.html.twig' %}

{# Include the reusable List Block via "use" statement above #}
{% block listBlock %}
    {{ parent() }}
{% endblock listBlock %}
```

**Content/ContentList.html.twig**

*The file that extends the `ListBase.html.twig` and successfully accesses the `entity` variable inside the `listRow` block that is inside the `for` loop that sets that variable.*

```
{% extends 'GutensiteCmsBundle:Cms:ListBase.html.twig' %}

{% block listRow %}
<tr>
    <td class="title">{{ entity.title }}</td>
    <td class="status">{{ entity.isPublished }}</td>
</tr>
{% endblock listRow %}
```

**View/ViewVersionEdit.html.twig**

*The file that uses `Cms/includes/ListBase-Include.html.twig` directly, just like `ListBase.html.twig` does, except it also attempts to overwrite the `listRow` block within the `listBlock` block. It can do that just fine, but it doesn't have access to the `entity` property in this case.*

```
{% extends 'GutensiteCmsBundle:View:ViewEditBase.html.twig' %}

{# Include the reusable List Block #}
{% use 'GutensiteCmsBundle:Cms:includes/ListBase-Include.html.twig' with link as list_link, script as list_script %}

{# Include the reusable listBlock blocks via "use" statement above #}
{% block listBlock %}
    {{ parent() }}

    {% block listHead %}
        <th class="revision">Revision</th>
        <th class="modified">Modified</th>
        <th class="published">Publish Date</th>
        <th class="notes">Notes</th>
    {% endblock listHead %}


    {#
    NOTE: This extends the listRow which is inside a for loop that loops through 
    view.data.list as entity. In a normal template that extends Cms/ListBase.html.twig, the 
    value of the loop is accessible in the listRow block. But since this is extending the 
    listRow from the "use" statement it's a little different.
    #}

    {% block listRow %}
            <tr>
                <td class="revision">
                   #{{ entity.viewId }}-{{ entity.id }}
                </td>
                <td class="modified">
                    {{ entity.timeMod | localizeddate('medium', 'short', 'en') }}
                </td>
                <td class="published">
                    {{ entity.timePublish | localizeddate('medium', 'short', 'en') }}
                </td>
                <td class="notes">
                    {{ entity.versionNotes }}
                </td>
            </tr>

        {% endif %}
    {% endblock listRow %}

{% endblock listBlock %}
```

Without reference to `entity` in the `listRow` block, the page renders and correctly displays all the included html layout from the referenced `use` template. And the blocks are overwritten successfully.

However, when the `entity` is referenced it gives the error:

```
Variable "entity" does not exist in GutensiteCmsBundle::View\ViewVersionEdit.html.twig
```

The `entity` variable is not present in the block in this context.

I have tried first declaring the `listBlock` and then after that extending the other blocks **outside** the block. And that still overwrites the block, but it doesn't help with the missing variable.

```
{% block listBlock %}
    {{ parent() }}
{% endblock listBlock %}

{% block listRow %}
    {# All the code here #}
{% endblock listRow %}
```

I have also tried with and without the `parent()` call, but that doesn't have the desired effect.

**Essentially there is a scope issue that I don't understand, which affects the blocks when they are extended from the same template that is using the `use` method.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your use case:

> I am using the *use* method in Twig 1.16 in order to include a reusable template in a way that lets me extend the blocks (something you can't do if you *include* the template).

I would suggest you simply use **embed**.

Source: twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/embed.html

You can override/extend blocks using the **embed** tag.

Comment: That worked brilliantly, for the `View/ViewVersionEdit.html.twig`. I tried using it for the main `Content/ContentList.html.twig`, but it seems like you can't extend a template that has an embed, and modify the embed area. But it works with the `use` statement in the original context so that's okay.

Comment: Another issue with this method is how to embed stylesheets or scripts from the embed skeleton. I thought I could do an extra include (not ideal but better than copy/pasting identical code), but in the first context it uses the `use` method, and the templates that use that need to call the `{% block link%}` to inject into the extending template...

Comment: Not sure if it helps but you can do ```{{ block('blockname') }}``` to render a block at a given position. Other than that I don't know how to help, but I'm pretty sure it is solvable with a combination of **use**,**include**,**embed** and **extend**.